# What does the "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main"" warning mean?

Tags: c

Immediately below is the error message I get:

```
} ^ 1 warning generated. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
    implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: 
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And here is the code itself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int isOddEven (int i) {
      for (i=0; i < 100; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
          printf("%d is an even number\n", i);
          return 1;
        }
        else{
          printf("%d is an odd number\n" , i);
          return 0;
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: There is no `main` function in your code.

Comment: Every C tutorial should explain that the program starts from the `main()` function.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. Well appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling a .C file: Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572665/compiling-a-c-file-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Answer (score 1):

You have not included the main method at all.
You have not declared the main method at the top.
In c you have to declare the function at the top like a variable first.
hence you first have to declare the isOddEven() function at the top.

your code should be something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void isOddEven();
int main()
{
  isOddEven();
  return 1;
}
void isOddEven() 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
      printf("%d is an even number\n", i);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%d is an odd number\n" , i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "method" wouldn't be the best way to describe `main` since methods don't exist in C. And you don't "have" to declare functions first before defining, you can just define them before `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isOddEven (int i) {
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int value = isOddEven(3);  
    if(value == 1){
        printf("Value is even");
    }
    else{
        printf("Value is odd");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here isOddEven returns a int value which you can check in your main function that value is odd or even.