# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 termcap.h in C

Tags: c, termcap

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *termtype = getenv("TERM");
    int li = tgetnum("li");
    printf("%d", li);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't compile it because I get

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_tgetnum", referenced from:
          _main in main-11560e.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is it happening?
MacOS Catalina

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling a .C file: Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572665/compiling-a-c-file-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: I have compiled my program with -c flag, but it refuses to run. "cannot execute binary file"

Comment: You left out `-lncurses` on the command-line (this is a duplicate).